# what is the 'selected' version of a color

Tags: wpf

I have an application and the user wants me to colorize some rows in a table based on some status he defines.
He currently chose 5 colors

- red
- green
- blue
- yellow
- brown

but the list can be expanded I guess.
I am using a cellstyle to apply this color and this works
But I want the user to be able to see the difference when he selects a row by using yet another color that somehow intuitively belongs to the base color.
So 2 rows with the same status say Red, but one of them is selected then the selected row should have the color 'selected red'.
How would I do this ?
Add 10 units with both R G and B ? Is there some kind of standard ?
How do I make a 'selected red' from red, in such a way that I can apply that concept to any color.

Comment: we have similar situation and we have a BLUE weird colored border around it...  changing colors might confuse end user for what is this whole new color about thing !

Comment: I don't think there is a 'selected' version of color.  There are lots of color wheel out there.  color.adobe.com is a good on.  It is hard to have a lot of contrast in a color and yet still have the text stand out out.

Comment: There is a "standard" selection color in Windows, it depends on the currently selected UI theme. You could overlay this selection color over your colors with some transparency applied.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for design help. Try http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hold one of the three RGB and then change the other two and keep the ratio the same.  In practice is there is not a set amount of how far to move the other two.  And you have to pick which one to hold.  I think it is easier just to use a color wheel to pick the colors.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:
I've got State class with color information and Model class, which have State info:

```
public class State
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public System.Drawing.Color Color { get; set; }

    public State(int id, Color color)
    {
        ID = id;
        Color = color;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ID.ToString();
    }
}
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }

    public Model(string name, State state)
    {
        Name = name;
        State = state;
    }
}
```

in view model:

```
public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<Model>() { 
            new Model("item1", new State(1, Color.Red)), 
            new Model("item2", new State(1, Color.Red)), 
            new Model("item3", new State(2, Color.Green)) 
        };
    }
```

and view:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StateToColorConverter x:Key="StateToColorConverter"/>
    <local:SelectedColorConverter x:Key="SelectedColorConverter"/>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding State.Color, Converter={StaticResource StateToColorConverter}}"/>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding State.Color,Converter={StaticResource SelectedColorConverter}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</Grid>
```

and finally converters:
StateToColor:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var color = (System.Drawing.Color)value;
        return new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));
    }
```

SelectedColor:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var newColor = ControlPaint.Light((System.Drawing.Color)value);
        return new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(newColor.A, newColor.R, newColor.G, newColor.B));
    }
```

It's make selected color lighter based on color which has State.